# How to convert tidyverse chains to a recipe?

Tags: r

I'm reading "Hands-On Machine Learning with R" by Bradley Boehmke & Brandon Greenwell where they suggest one should use the `recipes` package to set up various preprocessing steps. I want to implement this in my own modelling but I prefer exploring the data with tidyverse at first, grouping, filtering etc.

There is a function `step_mutate` in the recipes package but it doesn't allow for grouping and so I'm wondering if anyone has a system for how to combine both `tidyverse` and `recipes` in the modelling process?

For example, I'm practising with the [Spaceship Titanic data](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/spaceship-titanic/data) from Kaggle

```
train <- structure(list(PassengerId = c("0001_01", "0002_01", "0003_01", 
"0003_02", "0004_01", "0005_01"), HomePlanet = c("Europa", "Earth", 
"Europa", "Europa", "Earth", "Earth"), CryoSleep = c("False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), Cabin = c("B/0/P", 
"F/0/S", "A/0/S", "A/0/S", "F/1/S", "F/0/P"), Destination = c("TRAPPIST-1e", 
"TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "PSO J318.5-22"
), Age = c(39, 24, 58, 33, 16, 44), VIP = c("False", "False", 
"True", "False", "False", "False"), RoomService = c(0, 109, 43, 
0, 303, 0), FoodCourt = c(0, 9, 3576, 1283, 70, 483), ShoppingMall = c(0, 
25, 0, 371, 151, 0), Spa = c(0, 549, 6715, 3329, 565, 291), VRDeck = c(0, 
44, 49, 193, 2, 0), Name = c("Maham Ofracculy", "Juanna Vines", 
"Altark Susent", "Solam Susent", "Willy Santantines", "Sandie Hinetthews"
), Transported = c("False", "True", "False", "False", "True", 
"True")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I have a dplyr chain like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(recipes)

train2 <- train %>% 
  mutate(PassengerGroup = as.numeric(str_sub(PassengerId, 1, 4))) %>% 
  group_by(PassengerGroup) %>% 
    add_count(PassengerGroup, name = "PassengerGroupSize") %>% 
  ungroup()
```

In the recipe, I can implement the first part but I can't group or use other more advanced piping functions like nest etc.

```
my_recipe <- recipe(Transported ~ ., data = train) %>%
  step_mutate(
    PassengerGroup = as.numeric(str_sub(PassengerId, 1, 4))
  )
```

Is there a way to turn the piping process into a function and then use it in recipes? Like a `step_custom`?

Comment: This is a count encoder. Not sure how to bring it into the recipe in a clean way.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate :(